# University Email (Outlook) Changed and Auto-Updated in Browser and Google Account

Tags: privacy, email, account-security, google, outlook

I recently noticed my email address for the University I work for was changed - from "blank@university.edu" to "blank@ad.university.edu". I also noticed that the version of the email address saved in my browser and on my google account to keep track of my passwords was also changed to this new address. I already called my university's IT department and asked them what this means and they said this is some "backend thing" that I don't have to worry about, but they didn't really have an answer for why the address was autoupdated in my browser and google account, so I was just wondering if this is normal or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is because someone messed up and deleted the alias for the exchange server.
Your email address should end in @ad.university.edu as it is the default Active Directory Domain for your university, but you can add an alias @university.edu in order to make it look better. someone deleted this alias or changed the default display domain to ad.university.edu.

The update happened automatically because this is how it's supposed to be, automatic.

In other words, someone in the IT of your Uni messed up and there is nothing to worry about.

Source: I was a Domain Admin for a big corporation and have setup AD at home.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! This was vaguely worrying to me so I'm glad it wasn't anything dangerous in the end!